# Need a field in SELECT DISTINCT but I do not want it to be printed

Tags: mysql, select, field, visible

I need to have the ID field in the SELECT DISTINCT in order to differentiate 2 cases: duplicates from not duplicates but namesake.

In other words you may have the same person duplicated many times and people with same name and surname in the same db.

If I do not place the ID field in the SELECT, the query returns duplicates and namesakes.

I have to place the ID to eliminate duplicates only. But at the same time, I would like not to print the ID. IS this possible without using the group by ID?

SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name, Surname
FROM (SUBQUERY THAT RETURNS DUPLICATES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
Select c.Name, c.Surname 
  From (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name, Surname 
      FROM (SUBQUERY THAT RETURNS DUPLICATES)
  ) as c;
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought that voting was equivalent to accepting. Just amended

Answer (score 1):

A simple way a select wrapper

```
  select Name, Surname from ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT 
        ID
      , Name
      , Surname 
  FROM (SUBQUERY THAT RETURNS DUPLICATES) ) T
```